Reload nginx from crontab not working
I'm making a standard script: update nginx config by crontab and reload config

11 11 * * * /root/change.sh>> /root/script.log

#!/usr/bin/env bash

# do changes

echo "reload started"
service nginx reload
#nginx -s reload
echo "reload done"

I see an execution of script in syslog, but nginx config stays without reload.

Aug 31 11:13:01 t2 CRON[1073432]: (root) CMD (/root/change.sh >> /root/script.log)

And no new entry in service nginx log.
Update
systemctl instead of service command works as expected. But why?

systemctl reload nginx


Have you tried using systemctl in the script instead of service?
What are Cron Jobs and how to use them in Linux Systems?

I have wrote in the update, that systemctl works before your answer. You are right. Thx for link to document
